# Jquery error never seen before

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

i am developing a php web app and it was working correctly.
I worked with ajax and javascript the whole day and everything was ok (even in the console log), but this evening I re-opened the console and appeared this error

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'insertRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': Failed to parse the rule '::content a[href^="http://www.gamebookers.com/cgi-bin/intro.cgi?], ::content #adsensempu, ::content .mpu-top-left-banner, ::content .moduletable-advert, ::content #nib-ad, ::content #toppannonse, ::content .icon-advertise, ::content #outbrain-paid, ::content .header--ad-space, ::content .google_add, ::content #iframead-300x250, ::content #adbrite_inline_div, ::content .adv_top, ::content #upperAdvertisementImg, ::content #ksperAD, ::content #adsdiv, ::content .TopAds, ::content #ad_300x60, ::content .ad-in-post, ::content #bottomAdSenseDiv { display: none !important; }'.
at chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/include.preload.js:345:25
```

I have never seen it before. Does anyone know how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Post your code in your question.

Comment: That extension ID is AdBlock Plus, I believe. It probably thinks something in your application is an ad.

Comment: This error is displayed in all the pages, i don't know wich code post.

Comment: When you're on a page that is throwing the error, go to your AdBlocker interface click on "Don't run on this page" or "Don't run on pages on this domain".

Answer (score 4):

I just found this in my chrome browser, as well, and it seems to occur in all tabs, no matter the website.  If you go to the file in question

`chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/include.preload.js:345:25`

you'll find that it belongs to adblock plus.  I'm guessing that there was an update in the plugin that is causing it to fail on the mentioned method:

`CSSStyleSheet.insertRule()`

This will hopefully be fixed by the developer, but, in the meantime, disabling adblock plus on the site will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. I turned off  the ABP (Adblock Plus) . Now it works properly

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing this error, too, while developing an Angular app.

I updated my filter lists and the error went away.